# jupyter notebook / Failed to start the kernel due the KeyError

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, jupyter

My jupyter notebook doesn't start due the dead kernel with following Kernel error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1512, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 238, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1069, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 67, in post
    model = yield gen.maybe_future(sm.get_session(path=path))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 170, in get_session
    return self.row_to_model(row)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 209, in row_to_model
    raise KeyError
KeyError
```

Comment: Os? Enviornment like Conda or independent install? Also did the kernel die and then failed to restart or the kernel never started.

Comment: macOS, independent install, kernel fails to  start, returning:
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_prompt_application'

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue originated from having `prompt-toolkit` requirement conflict in `jupyter-console` and `ipython`.

You can use `pip check` to make sure whether you have the same problem. If the output is something similar to my output below, you have to fix the broken packages issue.

```
>>> pip check ipython 
ipython 5.0.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.3, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 2.0.9 which is incompatible. 

>>> pip check jupyter-console 
jupyter-console 6.0.0 has requirement prompt-toolkit<2.1.0,>=2.0.0, but you'll have prompt-toolkit 1.0.15 which is incompatible.
```

The quick fix is to try the solution originally mentioned [here](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/158#issuecomment-427023237).

```
pip uninstall prompt-toolkit 
pip install prompt-toolkit==1.0.15 
pip uninstall jupyter-console 
pip install jupyter-console==5.2.0
```