# jupyter notebook does not connect to kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to use jupyter notebook but it does not want to connect to the kernel.
I tried updating anaconda and started jupyter from the anaconda prompt.
I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1592, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1147, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 67, in post
    model = yield gen.maybe_future(sm.get_session(path=path))
  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 170, in get_session
    return self.row_to_model(row)
  File "C:\Users\felix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 209, in row_to_model
    raise KeyError
KeyError
```

Comment: I guess problem is solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437305/jupyter-notebook-failed-to-start-the-kernel-due-the-keyerror

Comment: No, does not work. I used conda not pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

downgrade tornado to 4.5.3 seemed to solve it. I can use jupyter via the conda prompt. But it still doesn't work together with VS Code.